# How to keep the original format of values after unlist(lapply(mydata, function(x) {x$getElementText()}))

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I'm trying to keep the original values format. The data format is:

```
 <option value="xxxxx                  ">xxxx                   </option>
      <option value="yyyy                 ">yyyy                  </option>
      <option value="zzzzzzz              ">zzzzzzz                 </option>
...
```

But, I'm getting this after using

```
unlist(lapply(mydata, function(x) {x$getElementText()}))

head(mydata)
[1] "xxxxx" "yyyy"  "zzzzzzz"
```

What I need:

```
 head(mydata)
    [1] "xxxxx                  " "yyyy                 "  "zzzzzzz              "
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: Thank you Mrflick! unlist(lapply(mydata, function(x) {x$getElementAttribute('value')})) work very well.

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementText` method normalized the text as it would appear in the browser. If you have a bunch of standard spaces between words in an HTML page, pretty much all browsers will render that as a single space. However, you can get the the underlying value from

```
 x$getAttribute('textContent')
```

which was found [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2608)

Or in your case if you want the value attribute from the option tag

```
 x$getElementAttribute('value')
```